# how to open *.info file in emacs in info mode?

Tags: emacs

`C-x C-f blah.info` opens the file in fundametal mode. I used `apropos` and found `Info-mode` which I thought might change from fundamental mode into Info mode, but that throws a lisp error.

How can I open a external/thirdparty *.info file in emacs so that I get the same bells and whistles as when I'm looking at `M-x info` (`n` for next, `u` for up, hyperlinks, etc..)? I'm sure this is obvious, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Plain (info `file-name') opens file in info mode. (info) probably does something besides just setting Info-mode. So I would use something like this:

```
(defun info-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((file-name (buffer-file-name)))
    (kill-buffer (current-buffer))
    (info file-name)))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.info\\'" . info-mode))
```

Comment: It seems that `info` serves mostly as a springboard to `info-setup`. Here's a similar function albeit without the `interactive` sugar of the original `info` function:

    `(defun info-find-file (file)
      (interactive "f")
      (info-setup file
                  (pop-to-buffer-same-window 
                   (format "*info*<%s>" 
                           (file-name-sans-extension 
                            (file-name-nondirectory file))))))`

Answer (score 70):

Try `C-u C-h i` (i.e., the usual info invocation with a prefix argument).

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 12):

When your cursor is on the filename in the `dired` buffer, press `I` (`shift` and `i`). Requires dired-x, which is part of GNU Emacs.

```
I runs the command dired-info
  which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `dired-x.el'.
It is bound to I.
(dired-info)

Run info on this file.
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use **org mode**. Type the following in a buffer already set using `M-x org-mode`:

```
info:path/to/blah
```

Then invoke **info** by placing the cursor over this and hitting `C-c C-o`. Alternatively, click on it with your mouse.  You can also set the whole thing in double square brackets, if you path contains whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.info\\'" . Info-on-current-buffer))
```

Comment: This answer is close, as OP specifically indicated they are looking to simply view the buffer in Info mode, not integrate it into the global Info system. But note that this `auto-mode-alist` config would typically be ignored in `.info` files since they have a file-local variable specification at the top of the file (like `-*-Text-*-`) which takes precedence over `auto-mode-alist` config (see https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SetAutoMode ). I haven't yet found an alternative to calling `Info-on-current-buffer` manually via a keybinding.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your .emacs initialization file:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist 
      (append '(("\\.info" . Info-mode)) auto-mode-alist))
```

Comment: This sorta worked but when I open a info file, none of the links are "active" until I navigate over one and press `RET`. I think @rzab is correct, seems like info does other stuff than just starting Info-mode. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

```
C-u C-h i
```

That will prompt you for the file to open. `C-u` tells the interactive command `info` to ask for an argument, which is the file name.

Comment: This answer was already given over 13 years ago. Please don't repeat answers.