# Emacs: Open a specific Info section

Tags: emacs, elisp

When i do `describe-function info`, documentation says: `Called from a program, FILE-OR-NODE may specify an Info node of the form "(FILENAME)NODENAME".`

I used this syntax to open specific sections in Emacs manual like `eval-expression (info "(emacs)mark")`.

But now i have three questions:

- How to find out filename of a certain info file? (example: "elisp" for Emacs Lisp Intro)
- How to find out the section name? (example: "mark" for "11 The Mark and the Region")
- Is it possible to list info files and their sections before calling one with `eval-expression`?
- Optional: is it possible to do all of the above without running info mode?

To clarify, my questions arise from the fact that the node name (example: "Shell") and title of a corresponding section (example: "36 Running Shell Commands from Emacs") differ.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> - How to find out filename of a certain info file? (example: "elisp" for Emacs Lisp Intro)

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> from the `*info*` buffer will tell you that the <kbd>c</kbd> key will `Put name of current Info node in the kill ring` (as well as displaying it in the echo area). From there you can yank it with <kbd>C-y</kbd> as usual.

The part of the node name in parenthesis *is* the name of the file (minus its suffix, and directory path).

To obtain the filename *including* its directory path (but still minus any suffix), you can call `(Info-find-file "file")` for the file in question ("emacs" in your example).

Note that the suffix for the file (if any) can be anything in the `Info-suffix-list` variable.

You *can* in fact pass a full file path as the argument to the `info` function as well. That's *generally* less useful, but may be handy if you managed to end up with conflicting info files. Interactively, <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> will prompt you for a full filename.

(To enter a node name interactively, you can use <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>.)

> - How to find out the section name? (example: "mark" for "11 The Mark and the Region")

That's essentially the same as the first question, except it's the part of the node name *after* the parentheses that you want. Again, just use <kbd>c</kbd> to find out.

> - Is it possible to list info files and their sections before calling one with eval-expression?

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by this, but maybe these help?

- <kbd>d</kbd> will jump to the main directory (as <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> takes you to initially). This is generated from all the `dir` files found in the directories in the `Info-directory-list` variable. Each `dir` file contains the paths for each file, but you're unlikely to need to see those.
- <kbd><</kbd> or <kbd>t</kbd> takes you to the top node of the file, which generally presents the top-level contents for the file.
- <kbd>T</kbd> opens an all-on-one-page table of contents for the current file.
- <kbd>I</kbd> presents you with index entries matching a pattern, for the current file.
- <kbd>C-s</kbd> can search through all nodes of the current file (simply type it again each time you hit the end of the current node to start searching in the next).
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `info-apropos` can be used to search *all* info files.

And obviously once you've arrived at a particular node via any method, you can use <kbd>c</kbd> to find out its name.

Also as previously mentioned, once you're in the `*info*` buffer, you can type <kbd>g</kbd> to go to any node in any info file, using the same `(file) node` syntax. You can omit `(file)` if you are already in that file, or omit `node` to get to the top node of the specified file. You may or may not prefer that to using
<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(file) node")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

As a special case, <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> renders the entire current info file in a single buffer.

Other useful Q&As on the general subject:

- [Reading multiple Emacs info files simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289256/reading-multiple-emacs-info-files-simultaneously)
- [how to open *.info file in emacs in info mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921049/how-to-open-info-file-in-emacs-in-info-mode)
- [info indexing (within and without emacs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122214/info-indexing-within-and-without-emacs)

Also:

- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InfoMode

And of course:

- <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(info) Top")` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>?</kbd>